# SWIFT - NSCocoaErrorDomain, Can' t open Document from documentPicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a Data from picked Document file (locally) via UIDocumentPickerViewController and I'm running crazy to figure out Why sometimes I'm catching an Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 error even that the file exist. I've tried code couple times and what I found is that if I have more than 5 items in the tableView then that don't want to work.

I'm working with tableView where user can add cell and add item like image, audio, video etc. When user take a cell with audio content, UIDocumentPickerViewController will show on and this function will be executed:

```
        if documentType == "audio" {
            print("INFO: Document(\(String(describing: documentType)) was picked at \(urls)")
            documentType = nil
            let audioItem = PostConstructor.CarBuild.audio(itemID: nil, audioURL: urls[0], index: self.items.count, loadedAudio: nil, itemType: PostProcessingFramework.CarBuildContentType.audio, title: "Edit your Audio clip title.", text: "Edit your Audio clip text.")
            self.items.append(audioItem)
            DataService.getDocumentType(fromPath: urls[0], completion: { ext in
                print("INFO: File extension is: \(ext)")
            })
        }
        
    }
```

there I've got variable with URL and whole my data struct is appended into items of tableView.  In this item you cannot change the URL and no other function is changing this variable. Then when user want to upload his work will be executed a funcion for upload:

```
 do {
      print("audioURL: \(audioURL.absoluteString)")
      let uploadData = try Data(contentsOf: audioURL)
      //function continue .....
 } catch {
      print("ERROR: \(error)")
 }
```

And here is the problem, I've tried this funcion couple times and it worked sometimes, whats weird that if I attepmted it with 4 other items than (my)audio, and only just 1 audio item it catched that error... however a variable printed before try Data()... printed a url that worked in last try. So my tries was:

> 1st attemp (1 item in tableView) **WORKED**
>
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/99FEC86E-75FC-4E0D-A236-BB2E8D9DED60/tmp/slovakianeast.Garage-Build-Inbox/New%20Recording%203.m4a

> 2nd attemp (5 items in tableView) **DID NOT WORK**
>
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/99FEC86E-75FC-4E0D-A236-BB2E8D9DED60/tmp/slovakianeast.Garage-Build-Inbox/New%20Recording%203.m4a

> 3rd attemp (2 items in tableView) **WORKED**
>
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/99FEC86E-75FC-4E0D-A236-BB2E8D9DED60/tmp/slovakianeast.Garage-Build-Inbox/New%20Recording%203.m4a

As you can see, the path is same but at 2nd try it wasn't working.
Please, help, my mind is about to blown up !

**Thanx !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally, I found out that for security reasons the urls gotten from UIDocumentPickerView will be dismissed after some time so instead of saving url I have saved asset from url.